# SQLException: Network error IOException:Connection refused: connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, talend

I am new to Talend application, while I am trying to connect to SQL Server database, I'm getting the error shown below. I googled it for resolve this issue few people were commenting as need to be start the SQL Server services in `services.msc` as they suggested I have enabled the services and but facing same issue so far.

Please kindly help me on this issue and find the attached screen shot which are  facing an issue.

Services error of SQL error 2:
[image: Services error of SQL error 2]

Talend error:
[image: Talend error]

Answer (score 0):

There is two option to connect to SQL Server,

> ```
> 1) Mix Mode 
> 2) Window Authentication
> ```

Use Microsoft SQL Management Studio and try  connect into the database.

Comment: I were used to connect windows authentication mode and i am able to connect successfully but I'm facing an issue in talend I've attached screen shots as well

Comment: did u turn on mix mode authentication?